# How do i create a CSV file from several different numpy arrays of different sizes

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have several numpy arrays of different sizes and want to store them in a single csv file.
When i try and do it using the following code

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({"Title" : titles_ht, "Authorname" : authorname_ht, "Article" : article_ht, "Summary" : shortsummary_ht, "Tags" : tags_ht})
df.to_csv("HT.csv", index=False)
```

i get an error saying that the arrays are of uneven size.

How do i create a csv file with each of these uneven arrays.

Comment: A properly formatted cav has rows with equal numbers of columns. How your arrays supposed to produce that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `numpy.savetxt()` function to export it as a csv file.

[Tutorial here](https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/big_data_and_business_intelligence/9781783553358/5/ch05lvl1sec50/writing-csv-files-with-numpy-and-pandas)